# Dúvida sobre concordância em número do verbo escrever

Tags: concordância

Em uma conversa informal, eu enviei a seguinte mensagem:

> É como eu e todo mundo no departamento de informática escreve artigos científicos

Meu amigo prontamente corrigiu a frase para que se lesse "escrevemos". Ele o fez sob a justificativa de que a concordância em número estaria incorreta pois "eu + eles = nós = 1ª pessoa do plural".

Mas ela está, no entanto? Me soa estranho, nesta construção, dizer "é como eu e todo mundo no departamento de informática escrevemos artigos científicos".

Comment: Israel, tens uma boa primeira pergunta; bem-vindo ao site! Ao considerar a opção "é como eu e toda a gente escreve", considera também a opção "é como eu e toda a gente escrevo"; encontras alguma razão para uma estar certa (ou errada!) que não se aplique à outra? :)

Comment: Acho que entendi o ponto. Neste caso "escrevo" concorda apenas com o trecho "eu", mas não com o "toda gente", assim como "escreve" apenas concorda com "toda gente".

Answer (score 8):

Tanto faz. A regra geral é um sujeito composto ir para o plural:

> Se o sujeito for composto, o verbo irá, normalmente, para o plural,
>   qualquer que seja a sua posição em relação ao verbo:
>
> > “... os ódios civis, as ambições, a ousadia dos bandos e a corrupção
> >     dos costumes haviam feito incríveis progressos”.
> >
> > “Repeti-as, porque se me ofereciam vida e honras a troco de perpétua
> >     infâmia”.

No entanto, «[p]ode dar-se a concordância com o núcleo mais próximo, *principalmente se o sujeito vem depois do verbo*». O teu caso encaixar-se-á (discutivelmente) ainda nesta observação:

> 4.ª) Pode ocorrer o verbo no singular ainda nos casos seguintes:
>
> a) se a sucessão dos substantivos indicar gradação de um mesmo fato:
>
> > A censura, a autoridade, o poder público, inexorável, frio, grave, calculado, lá estava.

Isto porque, admitindo que pertences ao Departamento de Informática, partes de *eu* para referir um universo maior em que te incluis.

Creio que o outro factor que favorece o singular nessa frase é o facto de o sintagma nominal *todo mundo no departamento de informática* ser muito longo, o que deixa o pronome *eu* muito longe do verbo.

Eliminados estes dois factores, soar-me-ia muito estranho ouvir:

> ?Eu e o resto do departamento escreve artigos científicos.

As citações são da *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa* de Evanildo Bechara (referências internas omitidas).

Answer (score 0):

A concordância ocorre em número e gênero, assim como em outros idiomas latinos. Eu e ele somos, logo, escrevemos.

Comment: Vale a pena checar a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5996/2764) do Artefacto, que menciona algumas nuances interessantes dessa questão.